# How to change time format

Tags: python

I have a python script which connects to a Db and returns the value of time in the format " %H:%M:%S\n"

I need to convert that time to seconds. How can I do this?

Below is an excerpt of the script which when run, returns a value such as `-2208987824.0`

```
p_out = p.stdout.read() 
times = [time.strptime(p_out, " %H:%M:%S\n")]
m1 = time.mktime(times[0].timetuple())
print m1
return 0

main()
```

Comment: Seconds since _when_?  Standard unix offsets?  The creation of the universe?

Answer (score 1):

If you need total no. of seconds then just put the following code sample

```
p_out = p.stdout.read() 
times = [time.strptime(p_out, " %H:%M:%S\n")]
sec s = (times[0].tm_hour*60*60)+(times[0].tm_min*60)+times[0].tm_sec
print secs
```

Comment: If you satisfy with my ans. then plz do UP VOTE for me and Make it as Right Ans.

Answer (score 0):

Use timedelta() method

```
import time
import datetime

sTime = "10:00:00"
tTime = time.strptime(sTime, "%H:%M:%S")
sec   = datetime.timedelta(hours=tTime.tm_hour,minutes=tTime.tm_min,seconds=tTime.tm
_sec).total_seconds()
print sec
```